# Create an XTS object with datestamps but no columns initially

Tags: r, xts

x is an xts object full of data; let's assume OHLC data for the sake of example.
I want to create another xts object, with the same size and datestamps, but different columns (e.g. some indicators).

My current approach feels crude:

```
a = x$close
for(nn in 1:10){
    z = analysis(x,nn) #Returns an enhanced version of x
    z2 = z$result   #Get out just the data I want, so I can rename the column
    colnames(z2) = paste("result",nn,sep="_")
    a = cbind(a,z2) #Merge in each result
    }
a$close = NULL  #Tidyup
```

I.e. I bring in just one column from x, any old column, just to get the structure, then throw that away at the end. (It works, so I'm happy, but it feels like there must be a better way.)

I tried some ideas like this:

```
a = xts(index(x))
a = xts(orderby=index(x))
a = as.xts(index(x))
a = as.xts(orderby=index(x))
```

But they give me empty XTS objects. E.g. when I then try this I get an error:

```
a$dummy = 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note the argument is `order.by`, not `orderby`.  That doesn't solve your issue though.  What you're looking for is:

```
a <- xts(order.by=index(x))
a <- merge(a, dummy=1)
```

`a$dummy <- 1` doesn't work because zoo objects can be a vector or a matrix, while xts objects are *always* a matrix and there's no `$<-.xts` method.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. Using a=xts(order.by=index(x)) instead of a=x$close in my example does indeed work (I.e. cbind works just as well as merge). However the a$dummy=1 syntax does work for XTS objects; it just seems it does not work for creating the first column. (E.g. following on from your two line example above, a$dummy2=1 will work!)

Comment: @Darren: sorry I wasn't clear. `a$dummy <- 1` doesn't work for creating the first column in an empty xts object because no `$<-.xts` method means `$<-.zoo` is called and an empty zoo object is treated like a vector, which causes `$<-.zoo` to fail.  I was trying to provide a little background on the error, but it was probably not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(xts)
L <- list()
L$x <- xts(1:4, as.Date(1:4))
L$y <- xts(1:4, as.Date(1:4))
do.call("merge", L)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think it is answering my question (or you're being too enigmatic ;-), but I tried it and it is an interesting technique that I'll try and bear in mind.